# Error: Multiple RestConsumerFactory found on classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

Getting error while calling `addRouteDefinition`. I am dynamically adding rest to camelcontext.

**Error**

> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException : Failed to create route ... because of Multiple RestConsumerFactory found on classpath. Configure explicit which component to use

```
RestsDefinition rests = camelContext.loadRestsDefinition(is);

camelContext.addRestDefinitions(rests.getRests());

for (RestDefinition restDefinition : rests.getRests()) {

        List<RouteDefinition> routeDefinitions = restDefinition.asRouteDefinition(camelContext);
        System.out.println(routeDefinitions);

        //camelContext.addRouteDefinitions(routeDefinitions);

        for (RouteDefinition route1 : routeDefinitions) {
            System.out.println("Route being Added : " + route1.getId());

            //Getting Error in this line
            camelContext.addRouteDefinition(route1);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `RestConfiguration` as the RestConfiguration was not set correctly on camelcontext so added. `camelContext.addRestConfiguration(restConfiguration);`

Comment: @ClausIbsen yes will do. it showing to wait for a day to mark as answered.